# django returning multiple values

Tags: django

My application provides 2 ways to login into website (same page). First is username & password and other is username & emergency password. I have backend.py as

```
class PersonAuthenticationBackend(object):
  def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
    try:
      person = User.objects.get(username=username)
      if person.check_password(password):
        return person
      else:
        try:
          db_ecode=person.get_profile().u_emergency_code
          if password==db_ecode:
            print "EMERGENCY LOGIN"
            return person
          else :
            return None
        except:
          return None
    except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
      try:
          return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
      except User.DoesNotExist:
          return None
```

Now how do I know if user has logged in using emergency login ??

Comment: Look for "EMERGENCY LOGIN" line in the output. :-) What task are you trying to solve?

Comment: the question is where in the code do you need to know that? you already know that when you print "EMERGENCY LOGIN" string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
person.a = lambda: None
setattr(person.a, 'login', True)
```

and then,
retrive using

```
print "person.a %s"%person.a.login
```

and then store it in session.

Answer (score 1):

This is python, you can dynamically add attributes to objects:

```
if person.check_password(password):
    person.loged_normally = True
    return person
```

and

```
if password==db_ecode:
    print "EMERGENCY LOGIN"
    person.loged_normally = False
    return person
```

If you want to have the information not only during one request but during entire session, then you have to save it to the session engine and/or database.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Code like this is very hard to maintain and test.

Answer (score 0):

Send a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#defining-and-sending-signals). Make a [log record](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/). Or you are looking for somethig else?

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a sessions which you can use later?